# Need help to build a sales funnel report by sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, powerbi

I have created a view for sales.In this view, there are relations among lead, opportunity and quotation. We can see not every lead turns to opportunity and quotation.

LeadID  OfferingID QuotationID Product Salesperson  Department  Date  Salesprice

```
L1      O1       Q1         X001     Mr.X       Machine Sales 11-01-2011  100
L2      O2       Q2         X002     Mr.Y       Marine Sales  10-02-2011  200
L3      O3                  X003     Mr.Z       Engine Sales  11-03-2011  300
L4      O4       Q3         X004     Mr.P       Parts Sales   13-04-2011  50
L5                          X001     Mr.X       Machine Sales 20-05-2012  100
L6      O5                  X001     Mr.X       Machine Sales 30-06-2012  100
```

My final output for the sales funnel for all department will be like [total number of leads (6)]->[total number of offering(5)]->[total number of quotations(3)].
If i want to filter it by 'Machine Sales' department ,the funnel will be like:
[total number of leads (3)]->[total number of offering(2)]->[total number of quotations(1)]..
i need to be able to filter the funnel by date,salesperson,product  and department.please help me to build this sales funnel query.
i will then visualize the data in microsoft powerbi after implementing the query  which will be in a funnel shape.

Comment: I think you have proper data you are getting from your view. all you need to do is just create 3 measure in your Power BI table for 3 different count. All other slicing options you mentioned will work automatically.

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there anything stopping you from feeding this data directly into Power BI?

I think you might be over-engineering this problem, and creating another table/view on you database that you'll have to remember/manage.

[image]
[image]

```
Leads = COUNT('YourTableNameHere'[LeadID])
Offers = COUNT('YourTableNameHere'[OfferID])
Quotes = COUNT('YourTableNameHere'[QuoteID])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward conditional aggregation with a group by:

```
select date
      ,salesperson
      ,etc
      ,sum(case when LeadID <> '' then 1 end) as NumberOfLeads
      ,etc
from YoutTable
group by date
        ,salesperson
        ,etc
```

If your `LeadID`, `OfferingID` and `QuotationID` columns have `null` values where there is no data you don't even need the conditional within the aggregate and can instead just use `count` as the `null` values are ignored:

```
select ...
      ,count(LeadID) as NumberOfLeads
      ,...
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select department, count(leadid) as num_leads, count(offeringid) as numoffers,
       count(distinct quotationid) as numquotations
from t
group by department;
```

I don't think `count(distinct)` is needed for the first two columns, but your data has no examples of duplicates so it is unclear.